# Can the same Spacy model take on different amount of memory, and if so what is the reason?

Tags: python, memory, spacy, psutil

I have been experiencing a thing I am not able to explain myself.
I want to find the impact in memory of a `spacy` model inside a Python process.

The question I am trying to answer is how many workers I can spin up with `gunicorn` given that each worker will have to load its own `spacy` model, the total amount of memory available in the Kubernetes node, and the max no. of replicas for the service when scaling.

To do so, I have the following script that

- loads a spacy model using `spacy.load()`,
- check memory usage using `psutil`.

I make sure to run `pkill -f python` before I run the script to start from a clean state.

```py
import psutil, os, time, sys

import spacy

B_TO_MB_CONVERSION_UNIT = 0.00000095367432

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    nlp = spacy.load(
        "en_core_web_lg",
        exclude=["tok2vec", "tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer"],
    )
    print(f"Loaded components: { nlp.pipe_names }")
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        print(process.memory_info())
        mem_usage = process.memory_info().rss * B_TO_MB_CONVERSION_UNIT
        print(f"Process takes {mem_usage} MB")
        now = time.time()
        if now - start > 10:
            sys.exit(0)

        time.sleep(1)
```

At first, I get this output:

```sh
Loaded components: ['ner']
pmem(rss=784879616, vms=5812686848, pfaults=305254, pageins=672)
Process takes 748.5195340706612 MB
pmem(rss=784883712, vms=5812686848, pfaults=305255, pageins=672)
Process takes 748.523440320676 MB
pmem(rss=784883712, vms=5812686848, pfaults=305255, pageins=672)
Process takes 748.523440320676 MB
pmem(rss=784883712, vms=5812686848, pfaults=305255, pageins=672)
Process takes 748.523440320676 MB
[...]
```

but then I get this:

```sh
Loaded components: ['ner']
pmem(rss=1125773312, vms=5842046976, pfaults=303825, pageins=504)
Process takes 1073.621097795748 MB
pmem(rss=1125777408, vms=5842046976, pfaults=303826, pageins=504)
Process takes 1073.6250040457626 MB
pmem(rss=1125777408, vms=5842046976, pfaults=303826, pageins=504)
Process takes 1073.6250040457626 MB
pmem(rss=1125777408, vms=5842046976, pfaults=303826, pageins=504)
Process takes 1073.6250040457626 MB
```

Further, I get this:

```sh
Loaded components: ['ner']
pmem(rss=909500416, vms=5858304000, pfaults=316778, pageins=3363)
Process takes 867.3984407686349 MB
pmem(rss=909541376, vms=5858304000, pfaults=316793, pageins=3364)
Process takes 867.4062532686644 MB
pmem(rss=909541376, vms=5858304000, pfaults=316793, pageins=3364)
Process takes 867.4062532686644 MB
pmem(rss=909541376, vms=5858304000, pfaults=316793, pageins=3364)
Process takes 867.4062532686644 MB
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here? I honestly thought then the same model would take the same amount of memory, give or take.

Comment: I think this has to do with RSS being a little wonky and depending on other processes and OS RAM magic. If you aren't making any documents a spaCy model will load the same data each time.

Comment: OK, that is interesting. I only do what the code shows. I actually measure memory this way as suggested from [this issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4432#issue-505823125). Do you have any alternative way of doing the same that you would suggest or recommend?